How to get the correct unicode from the HTML tag/text using javascript?
I am using Aspose to convert word to HTML and after converting the lists from word to HTML the symbols are something like <span style="font-family:Symbol"></span> this and on UTF-8 conversion the Unicode value for the symbol is \uf0b7 but on rendering it is showing this character \u2022 (•). I suspect it is because of the font-family: Symbol. So, is there any way to get the correct Unicode value considering the font-family property using javascript?

U+f0b7 is a private-use character. It's rendered e.g. as • (U+2022,  Bullet) in Symbol font, as (U+1F550, *CLOCK FACE ONE OCLOCK*) in *Wingdings* font, and as (U+1F3AC, CLAPPER BOARD) in Webdings…

Now I understand why it is bullet, thanks @JosefZ

The problem is that Windows “Symbol” font is a symbolic font (like “Webdings”, “Wingdings”, etc.) which uses Unicode PUA. MacOS or Linux “Symbol” as well as Noto Symbol font on the other hand is a proper Unicode font (for example Greek characters are in the U+0370…U+03FF Greek and Coptic block). So these fonts are incompatible and Mac/Linux “Symbol” font cannot be used instead of Windows “Symbol” without additional actions. For example the standard bullet in Windows Symbol font is U+F0B7 (or U+00B7 which also can be used in MS Word for symbolic fonts), but in Unicode font it is U+2022.
So the output produced by Aspose.Words is correct and it writes the bullet symbol, which is actually specified in the source document.
